# Selenium in crontab. How to open Firefox and run a script

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, cron

I have a code that works perfectly in Visual Studio Code and I wanted to run in crontab. Since it has the Selenium module, I didn't managed to run the code without errors.

Code to run in crontab (by [ipaleka](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57497746/selenium-crontab-script))

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
import time

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
options.add_argument("--headless")
driver.get("https://www.xe.com/currencyconverter/convert/?Amount=1&From=ISK&To=EUR")
loop = True
while loop: # This line is to avoid inconsistency
    try:
        #exchange_rate = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@class="converterresult-toAmount"]').text
        exchange_rate = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/section/div[2]/div/main/div/div[2]/div[1]/p[2]/span').text
        loop = False
    except NoSuchElementException:
        time.sleep(2)
driver.close()
print("Exchange rate updated: 0.00%s" % (exchange_rate))
```

**Error**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/<user>/Documentos/check.py", line 1, in <module>
    from selenium import webdriver
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'selenium'
```

### I've tried several ways to put in the crontab:

1. Define Display first, then open firefox and perform the script as [Luis](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23917386) said.

```
DISPLAY=:0
* * * * firefox
* * * * /usr/bin/env /usr/bin/python3 /home/<user>/Documentos/check.py >> /home/<user>/Documentos/log.txt
```

2. Define all the vars and then perform the script as [Jessica Chambers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57497746) and [Watty62](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64214433/15355884) did.

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/usr/local/bin/:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin/geckodriver
* * * * *  DISPLAY=:0 /usr/bin/python3 /home/<user>/Documentos/check.py > /home/<user>/Documentos/log.txt 2>&1
```

3. Put in a single line display and path with anaconda as [euh](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61915225/15355884) said.

```
* * * * * export DISPLAY=:0 && export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin && /home/<user>/anaconda3/bin/python3 /home/<user>/Documentos/check.py >> /home/<user>/Documentos/log.txt
```

4. Even with PyVirtualDisplay and Xvfb didn't work as [Muhammad Yasirroni](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66468045) posted it.
5. Create a bash script with all the variables and run that script in crontab as [Amit Ghosh](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63512312) said. (Log was empty, so maybe I didn't run it)

Bash script (cinkselenium.sh)

```
export DISPLAY=:0
export PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
nohup /usr/bin/python3 -u /home/<user>/Documentos/check.py > /home/<user>/Documentos/log.txt &y
```

Crontab

```
* * * * * /root/apps/bridge/cinkselenium.sh
```

**I have some points clear:**

- Always put absolute paths (not only in the files).
- You have to export PATH to let cron reach gecko drivers.
- You need to specify the Display.

I'm running this on Ubuntu 22.04.

Any help is welcomed.